# Need help to understand tf [from book: ROS by Example]

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
reading the book ROS by Example written by Patrick Goebel I m trying to understand and apply some basic concepts regarding tf.

At page 55 he explains an interesting code written using python in order to drive the simulated turtlebot using the transformation /odom and /base_footprint or /odom and /base_link.
Since I m really interested to understand ROS very well I tried on my owm to realize a similar program rewriting the whole code in C++.
Ok..let's start:
I wrote [half] code to move the turtlebot from the origin point (0,0,0) for about 1 meter without turning or making something strange. It just drives the turtlebot straight. Here is my code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>

#include <math.h>

class robotMovement 
{

protected:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher turtle_pub;

    tf::TransformListener listener;
    tf::StampedTransform transform;

    std::string odom_frame;
    std::string base_frame;
    std::string str;

    float linear_speed;
    float angular_speed;
    int rate;

public:
    robotMovement( std::string topic, float vel, float rot, int r )
    : str( topic ), linear_speed( vel ), angular_speed( rot ), rate( r )
    {
        this->turtle_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>( str, 10 );
        
        this->odom_frame = "/odom";

        try{
            this->listener.waitForTransform( this->odom_frame, "/base_footprint", ros::Time( 0 ), ros::Duration( 1.0 ) );
            this->base_frame = "/base_footprint";
        }
        catch ( tf::TransformException ex ) {
            ROS_ERROR( "%s", ex.what() );
            ros::Duration( 1.0 ).sleep();

        }

        try{
            this->listener.waitForTransform( this->odom_frame, "/base_link", ros::Time( 0 ), ros::Duration( 1.0 ) );
            this->base_frame = "/base_link";
        }
        catch ( tf::TransformException ex ) {
            ROS_ERROR( "%s", ex.what() );
            ros::Duration( 1.0 ).sleep();

        }
    }

    ~robotMovement( void ){
    }

    void moveStraight( float goal_distance ) 
    {
        float distance = 0.0;
        int counter = 0;

        /* Set the velocity vector */
        geometry_msgs::Twist msg;

        msg.linear.x = linear_speed;
        msg.linear.y = 0.0;
        msg.linear.z = 0.0;

        msg.angular.x = 0.0;
        msg.angular.y = 0.0;
        msg.angular.z = 0.0;


        ros::Rate loop( rate );

        do {

            try{
                
                listener.lookupTransform( this->odom_frame, this->base_frame, ros::Time( 0 ), transform );
                
                } catch ( tf::TransformException &ex ) {
                    ROS_ERROR( "%s", ex.what() );
                    ros::Duration( 1.0 ).sleep();
                }

            distance = sqrt( pow( transform.getOrigin().x(), 2 ) + pow( transform.getOrigin().x(), 2 ) );

            robotMovement::turtle_pub.publish( msg );

            ROS_INFO( "[%d], Distance: %6.4f", counter++, distance );

            loop.sleep();

        } while( ros::ok() && ( distance <= goal_distance ) );

        ros::spinOnce();

    }

    void moveStop( void ) 
    {
        /* Set the velocity vector */
        geometry_msgs::Twist msg;

        msg.linear.x = 0.0;
        msg.linear.y = 0.0;
        msg.linear.z = 0.0;

        msg.angular.x = 0.0;
        msg.angular.y = 0.0;
        msg.angular.z = 0.0;

        robotMovement::turtle_pub.publish( msg );
        ros::spin();
    }

};

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

    ros::init( argc, argv, "my_turtlebot" );

    robotMovement move( "cmd_vel", 0.8, 1.0, 10 );

    move.moveStraight( 1.0 );
    move.moveStop();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and works. BUT I realised soon that the robot is not moving 1 m (in RVIZ).
So I run in 2 separate consoles the toll to debug tf and I get

- Console#1: running `rosrun tf tf_echo /odom /base_footprint` it displays a differnce between /odom and /base_footprint about 0.84 m

> ```
> ....................
> At time 1407604810.474
> Translation: [0.840, 0.000, 0.000]
> Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
>             in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
> At time 1407604811.424
> Translation: [0.840, 0.000, 0.000]
> Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
>             in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
> At time 1407604812.374
> Translation: [0.840, 0.000, 0.000]
> Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
>             in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
> At time 1407604813.374
> Translation: [0.840, 0.000, 0.000]
> Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
>             in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
> ```

- Console#2: the calculated driven distance reported by the program is nevertheless

[ INFO] [1407604754.699373354]: [6], Distance: 0.5092
[ INFO] [1407604754.799364554]: [7], Distance: 0.6789
[ INFO] [1407604754.899417773]: [8], Distance: 0.8485
[ INFO] [1407604754.999370421]: [9], Distance: 0.9617
[ INFO] [1407604755.099385088]: [10], Distance: 1.074

So...the second output from console means that the turtlebot arrived in his goal position (1 m), BUT the "real" distance, according to tf debug tool, is a little bit smaller than 1 m.

So I have the following question:

- is this difference given by the lack of precision of the model between /odom and /base_footprint **or** is something wrong in my code?

The code to launch the turtlebot made by Patrick is available online and free to download (to be used with the book). I could write down the repository here if you need it!
Thanx in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189579/need-help-to-understand-tf-%5Bfrom-book:-ros-by-example%5D/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-10**:
i dont know about the example code, but from your code i can see you dont need angluar velocity if you just want to move in straight line. tf_echo displays frames at 1Hz. I think it may be due to timing. Put ROS_Info before return in main. Compare time with last timestamp of tf_echo

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-10**:
Why are your reply and my comments removed?
Can you typed again the caommand you told me?
tf tf_monitor

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-10**:
rosrun tf tf_monitor /odom /base_footprint; did you compare time stamps ?

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-01-17**:
hello, could you please share the book (ROS by example) to me??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-17**:
@Kishore Kumar: you can buy it [here](http://www.lulu.com/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-hydro-volume-1/ebook/product-21393108.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i would suggest asking the question to [ROS_BY_EXAMPLE google group page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-by-example). You will get appropriate answer there.

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0